# Qt: Add UI Elements using Qt Script

Tags: c++, qt, qtscript

Is it possible to add new GUI elements into a Qt program using QtScript?  For instance assuming the variable "layout" is a vertical layout would this be acceptable?

```
var label = new QLabel("Text");
layout.addWidget(label);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt doesn't ship with QtScript bindings; which bindings are you using?

If you're using the bindings generator on Qt Labs, yes, this code would work fine, assuming you arranged for the `layout' variable to be imported into your script engine.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that the bindings for QtScript needed to be generated.  I guess I'll be using the bindings made by the generator.  Thanks!